# raw pointer works in vector<T> while unique_prt does not

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11, unique-ptr

```
    vector<Universe*> vtd;
    Sweet* ptr = new Sweet();
    vtd.push_back(ptr); <--- WORKS FINE!

    vector<unique_ptr<Universe>> vtd;
    unique_ptr<Sweet> X (new Sweet());
    vtd.push_back(X); <--- Intellsense error!
```

Why does simply replacing raw poiner with unique_ptr fails to work in this scenario?

Universe is a class,

Sweet: Univers is derived class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason behind `std::unique_ptr` is that there can only be one owner of the pointer at any given time, with this in mind we can easily figure out that a `std::unique_ptr` isn't copyable.

`std::vector::push_back` normally makes a copy of it's argument to then store away this copy, but since we cannot copy a `std::unique_ptr` it will fail unless we take some action.

To store a `std::unique_ptr` inside a `std::vector` we will need to `std::move` the ownership into the vector, invalidating the one we have.

---

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Obj>> vec;

std::unique_ptr<Obj> my_ptr (new Obj);

vec.push_back (std::move (my_ptr)); /* `vec` now owns the pointer,
                                       my_ptr points to nothing    */
```

Comment: Thanks! Not I see why it did fail

Answer (score 0):

Try `vtd.push_back(std::move(X))`

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick. I'll go and google more about move operator, to understand exactly why did that work.